# Amazon AWS EC2 and RDS: How To Increase MySQL Query Cache?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I tried to find information about this, but can't find anywhere. The only one that I could find was

http://survivalguides.wordpress.com/2012/07/11/change-the-query-cache-size-amazon-aws-rds/

but it requires also following the instructions from

http://survivalguides.wordpress.com/2012/02/02/change-the-max_allowed_packet-amazon-rds/

Is this the only one available? Just wondering if it's the correct instructions. Do I have to follow the instructions from EC2 via SSH or from my local PC? My PC is running Windows 7.

Thank you.

Comment: What did AWS support say?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can also modify `query_cache_size` and `max_allowed_packet` parameters via the AWS Management console. Use this AWS documentation as your guide, [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html#USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.Modifying)

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for, have a great day!